# Using User defined table types in SQL Server for updating list of records

Tags: c#, variables, types, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-types

Team,

I am getting list of expenses as input parameter after that i created datatable and stored all the records and passing to the stored procedure as Datatable 
using User Defined Table types

1. User input value like expense List
2. Create DataTable and store all values
3. Pass into stored procedure as User Defined Table type

Code:

```
public ReturnTimeSheetExpSaveStatus SaveExpense(SaveExpenseInformation SaveExpense)
{
    ReturnTimeSheetExpSaveStatus RTSExpStatus = new ReturnTimeSheetExpSaveStatus();

    DataTable DtExpenseList = new DataTable();

    DtExpenseList.Columns.Add("TimeSheetID", typeof(Int32));
    DtExpenseList.Columns.Add("ExpenseBillableType",typeof(string));
    DtExpenseList.Columns.Add("ExpenseType", typeof(string));
    DtExpenseList.Columns.Add("ExpenseDays", typeof(string));
    DtExpenseList.Columns.Add("CurrencyConvertAmount", typeof(string));
    DtExpenseList.Columns.Add("CurrencyConvertBy", typeof(string));
    DtExpenseList.Columns.Add("UserInputExpAmount", typeof(string));
    DtExpenseList.Columns.Add("UserInputExpCurrency", typeof(string));

    foreach (var ExpenseSaveList in SaveExpense.ExpenseList)
    {
        DataRow DtRow = DtExpenseList.NewRow();
        DtRow["TimeSheetID"] = SaveExpense.TimeSheetID;
        DtRow["ExpenseBillableType"] = ExpenseSaveList.ExpenseBillableType;
        DtRow["ExpenseType"] = ExpenseSaveList.ExpenseType;
        DtRow["ExpenseDays"] = ExpenseSaveList.ExpenseDays;
        DtRow["CurrencyConvertAmount"] = ExpenseSaveList.CurrencyConvertAmount;
        DtRow["CurrencyConvertBy"] = ExpenseSaveList.CurrencyConvertBy;
        DtRow["UserInputExpAmount"] = ExpenseSaveList.UserInputExpAmount;
        DtRow["UserInputExpCurrency"] = ExpenseSaveList.UserInputExpCurrency;
        DtExpenseList.Rows.Add(DtRow);
        DtExpenseList.AcceptChanges();
    }

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[sp_PostSaveExpense]", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Domain_Id", SaveExpense.DomainID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeSheetID", SaveExpense.TimeSheetID);
            //ProductCat List table 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaveExpenseTable", DtExpenseList);

            SqlParameter ConsultantIDNameparameter = new SqlParameter();
            ConsultantIDNameparameter.ParameterName = "@ReturnTimeSheetExpSaveStatus";
            ConsultantIDNameparameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt;
            ConsultantIDNameparameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(ConsultantIDNameparameter);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            RTSExpStatus.TimeSheetSaveExpStatus = Convert.ToInt32(ConsultantIDNameparameter.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            RTSExpStatus.ErrorMessage = Ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return RTSExpStatus;
}
```

User defined table Type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[spCPMapp_SaveExpense] AS TABLE(
    [TimeSheetID] [int] NULL,
    [ExpenseBillableType] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ExpenseType] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ExpenseDays] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CurrencyConvertAmount] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CurrencyConvertBy] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [UserInputExpAmount] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [UserInputExpCurrency] [varchar](10) NULL
)
GO
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PostSaveExpense]  
(  
     @Domain_Id varchar(30),  
     @TimeSheetID int,          
     @SaveExpenseTable  spCPMapp_SaveExpense  READONLY,  
     @ReturnTimeSheetExpSaveStatus int output  
)  
AS   
--SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
SET NOCOUNT ON   
  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN

        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ID=@TimeSheetID )
        BEGIN   

            INSERT INTO tabke(Contractor_TESheets_ID,billableType,Expense_Type,Day_of_the_Week,currency,Amount)  
            SELECT [TimeSheetID] , ExpenseBillableType,  ExpenseType , ExpenseDays , UserInputExpCurrency, UserInputExpAmount 
            FROM @SaveExpenseTable WHERE ExpenseType <> 'Distance'
        END
END
```

When I execute this program, everything is working fine.

I raised the request to DBA team for moving these two objects into Production environment.

DBA team did not accept to run "User Defined Table type", they said, we never used User defined table type in Production around the company.

I explained to them, this is the feature to update list of values into single variables.

I need to explain them clearly to DBA team.

Can you help me?

1. If we use "User Defined table types " in Production, it would affect any perforamnce?
2. Each time if I execute this UDT , the value can store any of the place?
3. Features of User defined table type?
4. If any one of you using this kind of scenarios in your project?

Please share your suggestions

or

Is there any other simple way to achieve this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my application I've found that setting the SqlDbType seems to work.

```
//ProductCat List table 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaveExpenseTable", DtExpenseList).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay as far as I can understand your issue is:
- You need the user information into C# datatables which is later stored into SQL tables using a stored procedure.
- However, the DB team is not allowing you to manually define the columns and datatypes for the datatable.

If this is the case, there are 2 things you can try:

1.) No need for a datatable. You can simply run a foreach loop on the user inputs and passs them as SQLParameters.

2.) If you need to store the data inside datatables for future computations, you can get the schema from the SQL table into C# datatables by the following code:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your SQLConnectionString")) {
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 0 * FROM tabke", conn))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    };
};
```

You can debug the datatable (dt) and check its structure just to make sure that you have the correct results (columns).

I hope this helps. Good luck brother.